# Dynamically changing text in twitter button (rails+jquery)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter

Ok, so i have `index.html.erb`. In it I have menu, which I render from `_menu.html.erb`, and div, in which I render the link from `show.html.erb` by using show action in my controller. Link is shown by `<%=link_to h(@link), h(@link) %>` (code from show.html.erb).

Div, in which link is rendered, is often refreshed by `$('#div_with_link').load('controller/show');`, so @link changes a lot.

The problem is, that I don't know, what should I put in my twitter button text area. I want people to be able to share the current link. I've tried `data-text="<%=@video %>"`, but than it just showing the link on my webpage, not generated one.

What should I do, to put the generated link in my twitter button? Any suggestions would help, thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your description. Am I getting this right: You're displaying a link on your page. Then you're updating the link via AJAX. But a twitter is not being updated and shows therefore the wrong link?

Comment: And twitter button is located in different layout, than link, but they together are rendered in index.html.erb

Comment: Could you use jQuery to update the Twitter button once the AJAX request has finished? If you could provide the HTML for the button or an example online, I might be able to help you out there.

Comment: [link](http://maaaay.com/zalipay) here's the link, but please don't be afraid of some russian and crazy noobie code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, if you're using twitter's default button this will be pretty hard to achieve. I'd recommend to simply build [your own button](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button) and update the `href` attribute for this link via Javascript including the mentioned parameters. Here's some code to get you started:

Use this instead of your Twitter button and style it accordingly:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" id="tweet">Tweet</a>
```

Every time you load something new into the div, set the new URL (and other params if you want to) e.g. like this:

```
// not knowing your app, I'm just guessing here:
var twitterParams = { 
    url: <%= url_for(@video) %>, 
    text: <%= @video.title %> 
}; 
$('#tweet').attr('href', "http://twitter.com/share?" + $.param(twitterParams));
```

You could do that e.g. in the piece of HTML that you're returning when you're loading something new via AJAX.

Comment: @polarblau, it's looks like the right thing to do. Thank you for your support. I've done all what you've said and that's how my piece of HTML that I'm returning with the ajax looks like: `<%=link_to h(@video), h(@video) %>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 twitterParams.url = "<%= h(@video) %>";
 $tweetLink.attr('href', baseLink + "?" + $.param(twitterParams));
 </script>` but it gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: $tweetLink is not defined`. Am I using h() right?

Comment: Here is the full log of error from chrome dev tool: `(anonymous function)zalipay:3
jQuery.extend.globalEvalzalipay:540
evalScriptzalipay:785
jQuery.extend.eachzalipay:580
jQuery.fn.extend.domManipzalipay:4314
jQuery.fn.extend.appendzalipay:4073
jQuery.fn.extend.htmlzalipay:4220
jQuery.fn.extend.load.jQuery.ajax.completezalipay:4830
completezalipay:5279
jQuery.extend.ajax.onreadystatechange.xhr.onreadystatechangezalipay:5214`

Comment: Yes, the problem is probably that you have `$tweetLink` defined from where it can't be accessed like this. Simply replace `$tweetLink` with `$('#tweet')` and see what happens. By the way: As far as I know you don't have to use `h()` at all anymore in this case if you're using Rails 3.

Comment: You mean, i should have something like this? `var $('#tweet');
    baseLink = $('#tweet')[0].href` `$('#tweet').attr('href', baseLink + "?" + $.param(twitterParams));` Because I do have, and it's giving me _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (_ error on `var $('#tweet');`

Comment: Nope, sorry if I didn't make it clear enough. I'll update my example above. Also make sure that you don't use a semicolon in a case like this `var $('#tweet'); baseLink = …` —> `var $('#tweet'), baseLink = `. You're defining multiple variables in a row here. // And one more thing: Once you get this up, you'll have the next problem (it won't find `baseLink` probably), please check my latest update.

Comment: @polarblau, thank you a lot for your time! it still doesn't work (http://pastebin.com/WnCGeTS6) but i'm feeling bad for spending your time by lame questions and will try to figure that up on my own. you've gave me the right directions, thanks!

Comment: Try this: http://pastebin.com/zXUScA15 — you need to set the `href` attribute after setting the parameters. In the same fragment that you're loading via AJAX.